# Mail Report Error Is Not Of Type String

Tags: wordpress, reports

CiviCRM v5.48.2, WordPress v 5.9.3

I have a cron running as follows:

`/usr/local/bin/php /home/xxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cli.php -u xxxxxx -p xxxxxxx -e Job -a execute`

```
Entity: Job Action: mail_report
Summary Starting execution of Mail Reports

Details

Parameters raw (from db settings): 
instanceId=xxxx
format=PDF

Parameters parsed (and passed to API method): 
a:3:{s:7:"version";i:3;s:10:"instanceId";s:4:"xxxx";s:6:"format";s:3:"PDF";}

Full message: 
Starting execution of Mail Reports
2022-05-03 23:35:06 Mail Reports    
Entity: Job Action: mail_report

Summary Finished execution of Mail Reports with result: Failure, Error message: is not of type String
```

Comment: Anything in the civicrm log?

Comment: Too long to add. Seems to be starting here: May 04 23:18:27  [info] inactive contribution page access attempted - page number 2

May 04 23:18:27  [error] 
$Fatal Error Details = array:3 [
  "message" => "The page you requested is currently unavailable."
  "code" => null
  "exception" => CRM_Contribute_Exception_InactiveContributionPageException {#9799
    -id: 2

Comment: Here is the entire error which tends to repeat itself: https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/BncdZcrF

Comment: It appears that the mailings are now being sent:  
Entity: Job Action: process_mailing
Summary
Finished execution of Send Scheduled Mailings with result: Success (a:1:{s:9:"processed";i:0;})
Details

Parameters parsed (and passed to API method): 
a:1:{s:7:"version";i:3;}

Full message: 
Finished execution of Send Scheduled Mailings with result: Success (a:1:{s:9:"processed";i:0;})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently what fixed this was that I had to obtain the InstanceId that I pulled by selecting one of the Mailing Reports (I went to Reports - Mailing Reports - and then chose the Summary. In the browser I identified the number of the report which came after "instance%XXXX" and used the "XXXX" as the number. I entered the number by going to Admin - System Settings - Scheduled Jobs and it gave me all of the reports from which I selected Mailing Reports and then clicked the edit button which allowed me to edit both the InstanceId and the format. I selected "PDF" for the format. Not sure if the format is right, but the job runs now.

Comment: We're having the same issue. However, when I bring up the Summary Report as in your description above, I get no results. Is there another way to get the instanceId?

Answer (score 1):

Encountering a similar problem, with similar logs, except that my instance ID is set to "[ID of report instance]," which had, evidently always worked before.

At the moment, I don't even have a mailing to run reports on, though we're about to do a big one and I need to make sure this is working.

> Parameters parsed (and passed to API method):
> a:3:{s:7:"version";i:3;s:10:"instanceId";s:23:"[ID of report instance]";s:6:"format";s:3:"pdf";}
>
> Full message:
> Finished execution of Mail Reports with result: Failure, Error message:  is not of type String